# BINGO GAME in C , MATRIX WITH 3 Dimensions?

Tags: c, matrix, multidimensional-array, random, dimension

How can I generate some random cards with numbers, but I need manipulate them as a 3 dimenson matrix . [players][n][n] .. n = The dimenson

My program generates only one card, how can I generate more cards? The index of the cards will be set in the variable players( jogadores in the program) that is the first dimension of the Matrix

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n, soma;
int jogadores;
int menu;

int
main()
{
    srand(123);

    printf("Número de jogadores: \n");
    do {
        scanf("%d", &jogadores);
    } while (jogadores < 2 || jogadores > 10);

    printf("Numero de jogadores salvo \n Escolha a dimensao das cartelas: \n");
    do {
        scanf("%d", &n);
    } while (n < 2 || n > 9);

    printf("\n Dimensao das cartelas salva \n ");

    //printf(" %d %d \n ",jogadores,n);

    int value = 10 * n;

    // I need to add the dimensiona _jogadores_ ==> cartela [jogadores][n][n]
    int cartela[n][n];

    // Loop number of players
    // for (int q = 0; q <=jogadores;q++)
    // {
    // Loop lines of the card
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        // Loop rows of the card
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            do {
                soma = 0;
                // Colocar a dimensão jogadores
                cartela[i][j] = rand() % value;

                for (int l = 0; l < n; l++) {
                    for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
                        if (cartela[i][j] == cartela[l][c] && (i != l && j != c)) {
                            soma++;
                        }
                    }

                }

            } while (soma != 0);

        }
    }

    // for (int j = 0; j < jogadores; j++)
    // {
    for (int l = 0; l < n; l++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
            printf("\t %d", cartela[l][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    // }

    //while(1)
    //{
    //}

    return 0;
}
```

That's my code, and like I said before, the biggest question is how can i use the 3 dimension matrix to get more cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things ...

The main issue is that you should break down the `main` into some separate functions.

That way, you can create a function that creates a card. Then, you can call it N times for the number of players.

The card creation you have could take a long time and is very slow. Better to fill the array linearly and then randomly swap cells. This guarantees uniqueness but is much faster.

Here's a refactored version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n, soma;
int jogadores;
int menu;

void
card_print(int n,int card[n][n],const char *reason)
{

    printf("\n");
    printf("%s:\n",reason);

    for (int irow = 0;  irow < n;  ++irow) {
        for (int icol = 0;  icol < n;  ++icol)
            printf(" %2d",card[irow][icol]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void
card_init(int n,int card[n][n])
{

    int cardno = 0;
    for (int irow = 0;  irow < n;  ++irow) {
        for (int icol = 0;  icol < n;  ++icol)
            card[irow][icol] = cardno++;
    }

    // randomly swap cells in card
    int passmax = n * n;
    for (int passno = 0;  passno < passmax;  ++passno) {
        int irow = rand() % n;
        int jrow = rand() % n;

        int icol = rand() % n;
        int jcol = rand() % n;

        int tmp = card[irow][icol];
        card[irow][icol] = card[jrow][jcol];
        card[jrow][jcol] = tmp;
    }
}

int
main()
{
    srand(123);

    printf("Número de jogadores: \n");
    do {
        scanf("%d", &jogadores);
    } while (jogadores < 2 || jogadores > 10);

    printf("Numero de jogadores salvo \n Escolha a dimensao das cartelas: \n");
    do {
        scanf("%d", &n);
    } while (n < 2 || n > 9);

    printf("\n Dimensao das cartelas salva \n ");

    //printf(" %d %d \n ",jogadores,n);

    //int value = 10 * n;

    // I need to add the dimensiona _jogadores_ ==> cartela [jogadores][n][n]
    int cartela[n][n];
    card_init(n,cartela);
    card_print(n,cartela,"Single");

    int players[jogadores][n][n];
    for (int iplayer = 0;  iplayer < jogadores;  ++iplayer) {
        char msg[100];
        card_init(n,players[iplayer]);

        sprintf(msg,"Player %d",iplayer);
        card_print(n,players[iplayer],msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the program output for 3 players and card dimension 7:

```
Número de jogadores:
Numero de jogadores salvo
 Escolha a dimensao das cartelas:

 Dimensao das cartelas salva

Single:
 13 34 19 44 15  5 47
  7 25 32 48 16 28  0
  9 11  2 17 18  4 42
 36 41 12 23  8 39  6
 24 38 31 29 27 20 26
  1 21 37  3 14 10 22
 46 43 35 45 40 33 30

Player 0:
  7 30 17 23 11  2 15
 10 38  0 21 34 25  3
  6 40 12 46 18 22 41
 47 26 19 36 13 16 31
 33 28  1 35 27 14  4
 20 39  5  8 42 29 32
  9 43 44 45 24 37 48

Player 1:
  0  8 22 18  2  5 21
 20 29 16 10  7 42 24
 14  1 37 17  3 13 32
 31  6 23 39 15 11 45
 28  9 43 25 19  4 36
 35 12 47 38 40 30 44
 41 33 48 27 46 34 26

Player 2:
 40 44 18  3 28  5 43
 13 39 42 16 17  4 35
 27 23 14 45 37 41 30
 21 22 15  9  0 26 47
 46 12 11 31  2  7 20
  8 29 48 38 33 32  1
 24  6 25 36 19 34 10
```